# I have Honda Accord 2018 Touring , Navigation Display Screen not working

Tags: honda, battery, accord, battery-drain, fuse

I have Honda Accord 2018 Touring, my brother mistakenly reversed the connections to the battery terminals and now the the Navigation display screen won't power on.[image: photo of dashboard]

Comment: What does "turned the battery terminals" mean? If the car starts and runs, the battery and connections are fine. A fuse may be blown.

Comment: I mean he connected the negative to positive and the other way round. I checked all the fuse and it seems none of them is blown.

Comment: You checked all three fuse boxes, right? Two under the hood and one in the passenger compartment to the left of the driver's knees?

Comment: 1-Again. Does the car start up or not?
2-In addition to three fuse panels, does the radio have a built-in fuse?